# Get a list of all children by parent node guids

Tags: kentico

Is it possible in Kentico in c# to get a list of all children by a list of parent node guids?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like this:

```
        var parents = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
            .Columns("NodeID")
            .Where("nodeguid IN ('DB472111-B6EB-49F9-B98A-53FF2A0BCCF7',
                            '4A7ABB74-33A1-45BB-B382-8C368BDB26F0')");

        var mylist = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
            .WhereIn("NodeParentID", parents)
            .OnSite("CorporateSite")
            .Culture("en-CA")
            .ToList();
```

First will return type multidocumentquery (all nodeIds of the parents). Second will add them in *WHERE* condition and will run the query against the DB. Important note: it is one DB request not two.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the children by parent guid using DocumentQuery. Should be something like:

```
DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
.WhereEquals("NodeParentID", GUID);
```

If you need children for multiple pages simply add or and another guid.

For more details see [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/reference-documentquery-methods).

Comment: `NodeParentID` is an integer which is not compatible with SQL `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: Sorry, for typo! obviously you should use either .WhereEquals("NodeParentGUID", GUID) or .WhereEquals("NodeParentID", ID)